# Formatting C# Chart Axis Using CultureInfo

Tags: c#, charts

Currently i set Y axis of my chart using N2 format like this

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:N2}";
```

What i want to achieve is that N2 is using Indonesian format, i know how to do it in object conversion just like below

```
sum.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("id-ID"));
```

How to apply CultureInfo in formatting chart axis?

Comment: Which charting component you're using? Share the link to its documentation

Comment: i'm using charting component from visual studio 2013 itself, not a 3rd party component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `FormatNumber` event of the chart.

```
private readonly CultureInfo indonesiaCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("id-ID");
void chart1_FormatNumber(object sender, FormatNumberEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ElementType == ChartElementType.AxisLabels)
    {
        e.LocalizedValue = e.Value.ToString("N2", indonesiaCulture);
    }
}
```

Or you can change the `Thread.CurrentUICulture` for the UI thread and set `LabelStyle.Format` property. I've not tested it, I believe that should also work.

Comment: nice, works well, i have accepted your answer, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sriram Sakthivel's answer.
You can use Format property this way:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "IndonesianNumericFormat";

void chart_FormatNumber(object sender, FormatNumberEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Format)
    {
        case "IndonesianNumericFormat":
            e.LocalizedValue = e.Value.ToString("N2", new CultureInfo("id-ID"));
            break;
    }
}
```

So, you can set different formats to different columns and incapsulate logic of string conversion to a class \ factory etc.